# OpticalDrive Label Rename

Tags: windows-7

Please note that I did already follow to the "T" the instructions given from numerous web sites about going into the registry and entering my own label at the key called DriveIcons DefaultLabel  The system does enter my own label, but the system appends it to it's own label.

Is there a way to label an optical drive with your own label without the system appending it to the existing label? See example problem here below:

'CD ROM F Jim's Drive'

I want it to be only 'Jim's Drive'